# Javascript call function

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, call

I have been testing some code lately trying to understand javascript a little bit better. Then I came across the `call()` function wich I can't get to understand well.

I have the following code:

```
function hi(){
    console.log("hi");
}

var bye = function(param, param2){
    console.log(param);
    console.log(param2);
    console.log("bye");
}
```

If I call `bye.call(hi(), 1, 2)`, I get `hi 1 2 undefined`

And if I call `bye.cal(1,2)`, I get `2 undefined bye undefined`

for which I understand the `call()` function first parameter has to be a function, followed by the amount of parameter my `bye` function accepts. But where is the last undefined coming from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This first parameter doesn't have to be a function.  The first parameter is the object to which the "this" variable is set to in the context of the function call.

```
var bye = function(param, param2){
    console.log(param);
    console.log(param2);
    console.log("bye");
    console.log(this.x)
}

t = {'x': 1};

bye.call(t, 1, 2);
```

And the console should show: 1, 2, "bye" and 1.

The undefined is the return value of your function.

In your first call:

```
bye.call(hi(), 1, 2)
```

You're calling hi() (so it prints 'hi'), the return value is not used, and 1 and 2 are the parameters to bye.

In your second call:

```
bye.cal(1,2)
```

1 is assigned to this.  2 is param, and param2 is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the undefined because you function does not return anything, it only prints output to the screen.  So, your code could be like this:

```
var obj = {foo: "hi"};
var bye = function(param, param2){
    console.log(this.foo);
    console.log(param);
    console.log(param2);
}

bye.call(obj, 1, 2)   // "hi", 1, 2
```

You can read [here at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) for more info on `.call()`.

Answer (score 1):

`fn.call()` allows you to set the value that `this` will have when the function is called.  That value of `this` must be the first argument to `fn.call()`.

Answer (score 0):

call method required all the parameter individually apply method required all parameter in an array explained with example.

```js
let solarSystem = {
    sun: 'red',
    moon : 'white',
    sunmoon : function(){
       let dayNight = this.sun + ' is the sun color and present in day and '+this.moon + ' is the moon color and prenet in night';
        return dayNight;
    }
}

let work = function(work,sleep){
    console.log(this.sunmoon()); 
    // accessing the solatSystem it show error undefine sunmmon untill now because we can't access directly for that we use .bind(),.call(),.apply()
    console.log('i work in '+ work +' and sleep in '+sleep);
}

let outPut = work.call(solarSystem,'day','night');
let outPut1 = work.call(solarSystem,['day1','night1']);
let outPut2 = work.apply(solarSystem,['day2','night2']);
```