# Access Parent method from child Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, scope

How can I access baz() from inside the bar() function in the following code?

```
var obj = {
    baz : function(){ alert("Hi!"); },
    foo: {
        bar: function(){ 
            baz(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: obj.baz will work in this simplified case

Comment: That's not a "parent" in the OOP sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't have kind of a built-in parent reference because an object can be referenced by multiple 'parents' in what we call a many-to-one relationship.

As others have said, in this simplified case, simply calling `obj.baz()` will work.

In a more complicated case, you would have to manually build the object and track parenthood:

```
// Create the root object
var rootObject = {baz: function() {console.log('rootBaz');}}

// And the basic child
var childObject = {foo: function() {console.log('childFoo');}}

// Configure the parent
childObject.parent = rootObject;

// Add our call.
childObject.baz = function() {this.parent.baz()};

// Invoke and test
childObject.baz();
```

Which can be slightly simplified:

```
var rootObject = {
  baz: function() {console.log('rootBaz');}
};

var childObject = {
  foo: function() {console.log('childFoo');},
  baz: function() {this.parent.baz()}
};

childObject.parent = rootObject;
childObject.baz();
```

**Updated per Sujet's comment**

In addition, if you need to make sure that `baz` has the correct value for `this` you can use either [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

```
  baz: function() {this.parent.baz.call(this.parent)}
```

If your code doesn't require `this` then I would recommend a straight function call per my original answer.

Comment: Maybe explain *call* and *apply* function. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17017115/javascript-call-function

Comment: Thanks @HorsSujet.  Done.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the object reference:

```
var obj = {
    baz : function(){ alert("Hi!"); },
    foo: {
        bar: function(){ 
            obj.baz(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference via object.property notation.

In your example you would get baz via:

```
obj.baz()
```

**Some great resources for this**:

- http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects